# How to find a date and time stamp in a file using VBscript?

Tags: vbscript

I have an online temperature logger that publishes the date and time of last measurement in a file.

I need to find the date and time stamp in the html file using VBscript, and then check if it's older then 2 hours comparing to current time.

**Example date format:** `12.04.2013 16:45`

Comment: `12.04.2013` is a very bad choice for a technical date in a file. Use [ISO 8601](http://xkcd.com/1179/). Apart from that you did not tell what you have tried so far and you did not show any code you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the timestamp with a regular expression

```
\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}
```

However, due to the characteristics of HTML this is prone to error (line-wrapping, inline tags, …), so a better approach would be to extract the date from the HTML using DOM methods (e.g. `getElementsByTagName()`.

Once you have the date string, you can use the `DateDiff` function to calculate the difference to the current timestamp:

```
DateDiff("h", datestring, Now)
```